# Deploying Maven artifacts to different repos

Tags: maven, deployment, war, rpm

I have a Maven build process that generates 2 war files, and a number of RPM's to install the wars and environment-related properties files. The RPM's have to go into a Nexus-based YUM repo on one server, while the wars have to go into a Nexus repo on a different server.

My question is: how can I deploy the different artifact types to the different repos, ideally with a single mvn call?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/ideas.

Comment: Figured it out myself. Create a separate pom file to call the RPM plugin, and set a different distributionManagement element in it to upload to the RPM repo. This means there'll be 2 Maven calls in the build process - one to generate the jar/war artifacts, a second to call the RPM pom file. For the RPM pom, the expectation is the 1st Maven call has run and the jar/war artifacts are in a known location for packaging purposes.

Comment: You can also try using different profiles, then you can just use one pom.xml file.